# Component re-renders when setState called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

**React native PanResponder draggable interrupted by setState**

I'm having a state variable to track the seconds

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (seconds > 59) {
          setSeconds(0)
        } else {
          setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1)
        }
      }, 1000)
    
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
 }, [seconds])
```

I'm also using a pan responder draggable

```
import React, { useState, useRef, ReactNode } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  PanResponderGestureState,
  Text
} from 'react-native'

const Draggable = (props) => {
    const { draggable, isDropZone, moveToDropArea } = props
    const [showDraggable, setshowDraggable] = useState(true)
    const pan = useRef<Animated.AnimatedValueXY>(new Animated.ValueXY()).current
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        {
          dx: pan.x,
          dy: pan.y,
        },
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
        if (isDropZone(gesture)) {
          setshowDraggable(false)
          moveToDropArea()
        } else {
          Animated.spring(pan, {
            toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start()
        }
        pan.flattenOffset()
      },
    })
      return (
        <Animated.View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={[pan.getLayout()]}>
          <Text>{seconds}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      )
  }
```

When I try to drag the draggable, its moves but when the state updated the component rerenders and the Draggable item goes back to the original place.

How to prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the seconds from the dependencies. Because when the second variable changes it triggers the useEffect hook.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo)?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan if I remove the seconds from the dependency list the UI won't be updated with seconds

Comment: The problem is you are re-defining the interval every time the second changes. Put the interval out of the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your useEffect hook like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds(currentSeconds => currentSeconds > 59 ? 0 : currentSeconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

This way it will not be triggered every time seconds' state changes.

However, changing the state will still make your component rerender. If you want to prevent rerendering, you should use useRef instead of useState.

```js
const seconds = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        seconds.current = seconds.current > 59 ? 0 : seconds.current + 1;
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [seconds]);

console.log(seconds.current); // will log the last saved number of seconds before the last re-render
```

But if you need to display the changes of the seconds, you will need your component to rerender on seconds state change. In this case, I suggest you separate your scroll logic to another (maybe parent) component so it would not be reset on re-renders that are caused by the seconds' state change.

Answer (score 0):

Pass empty array in second parameter of useEffect hook.

The useEffect hook runs the callback function when a component mounts to the dom, which is similar like componentDidMount life cycle method in class components.

The setInterval function runs the setSeconds method for every one second.

Inside the useEffect hook we are returning a clearInterval function with a timer argument, so that setInterval function is stopped when a component unmounts from the dom, which is similar like componentWillUnmount method.

empty array will run useEffect on mount, remain silent throughout its life.

```
useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (seconds > 59) {
          setSeconds(0)
        } else {
          setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1)
        }
      }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
 },[])
```